# Don't open spring board on visionOS at app launch?

Tags: visionos

Every time I run my app in the Vision Pro simulator, the spring board (or whatever the app launcher on visionOS is called) opens. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: is this still a problem in visionOS Beta 2?

Comment: Nope, this seems to be resolved!